# Vertical aligning in minipage with picture and text

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage, overleaf

Can someone explain me why on my left minipage the text is not aligned at the top and how I get could it aligned at the top?

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
Wie viele Zahlen aus $G$ sind
\begin{itemize}
    \item[a)] Durch 8 oder durch 12 teilbar?
    \item[b)] Durch 12, aber nicht durch 8 teilbar?
    \item[c)] Weder durch 12 noch durch 8 teilbar?
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=1mm, fill,
              node contents={}}
                        ]
\def\firstcircle{(-1.2,0) coordinate (a) circle (2cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(1.2,0) coordinate (b)  circle (2cm)}
    \begin{scope}
\clip \secondcircle;

    \end{scope}
\draw \firstcircle;
\draw \secondcircle;
\node (c) [above] at (current bounding box.north -| a) {$V_8$};
\node at (c -| b) {$V_{12}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `[t]` optional argument to `{minipage}` the *baselines* of the top lines are aligned. However, the `tikzpicture` has by default its lower point on the baseline, see

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
Wie viele Zahlen aus $G$ sind
\begin{itemize}
    \item[a)] Durch 8 oder durch 12 teilbar?
    \item[b)] Durch 12, aber nicht durch 8 teilbar?
    \item[c)] Weder durch 12 noch durch 8 teilbar?
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
SEE HERE  % <------------------------- ONLY FOR EXAMPLE
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5,  % <---- ONLY FOR EXAMPLE
dot/.style = {circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=1mm, fill,
              node contents={}}
                        ]
\def\firstcircle{(-1.2,0) coordinate (a) circle (2cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(1.2,0) coordinate (b)  circle (2cm)}
\begin{scope}
\clip \secondcircle;
\end{scope}
\draw \firstcircle;
\draw \secondcircle;
\node (c) [above] at (current bounding box.north -| a) {$V_8$};
\node at (c -| b) {$V_{12}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can move the baseline of the `{tikzpicture}` with the `baseline` option. For example, since you have a node `(c)` with the text V<sub>8</sub> in it, you can align the baseline of this text by writing

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   baseline=(c.base),
   scale=.5,  % <---- ONLY FOR EXAMPLE
   ...]
  [ rest of code here ]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and you'll get

[image]